# How to setup rake to compile mruby gems?

Tags: rake, mruby

I am trying to build the example gem from [here](https://github.com/mruby/mruby/tree/master/examples/mrbgems/c_extension_example) following the mruby [documentation for building gems](https://github.com/mruby/mruby/blob/master/doc/guides/mrbgems.md).

I'm on a Mac OS Catalina, and I have installed RVM to manage my installation mruby. Right now `which ruby` returns `/Users/mdorier/.rvm/rubies/mruby-2.0.1/bin/ruby` so I can see that mruby is used.

The example gem above has an mrbgem.rake file, so even though the documentation doesn't explain how to build the gem, I suppose `rake` should be invoked in that directory. I didn't have rake installed, so I tried to install it with `gem install rake`, but it seems that Mac OS's native `gem` executable in /usr/bin got invoked, apparently installing the normal ruby's rake gem. When I call that rake, it doesn't find a Rakefile in the directory. If I specify `rake -f mrbgem.rake`, it tells me `NameError: uninitialized constant MRuby`.

I see that mruby doesn't have a gem command but seems to have a mgem that can be installed with gem. I installed it. I see that there is a `mruby-rake` mgem available, which I activated using `mgem add mruby-rake`, but it doesn't change what the `rake` command points to.

Can someone explain how I can install and use the proper rake command to build this mruby gem?